# How to get 18-digit current timestamp in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, time, timestamp

I want to get current timestamp like this:

```
636110767775716756​
```

However, when I do :

```
NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
```

It returns a value like this:

```
1475491615.71278
```

How do I access current time stamp ticks in the format I want? I check the dates from [here:](http://tickstodatetime.com/)

Comment: exactly you need current date and time as string .. ?

Comment: Yes I need it as string, in 18 digit format.

Comment: What's the origin/form of that timestamp? The issue is that the `timeIntervalSince1970`'s leading digit is currently `1`, which doesn't really match with what you're looking for.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620342/swift-convert-nsdate-to-c-sharp-ticks

This is what i am looking for but in Swift.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You seem be looking for what [`DateTime.Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) is in C#, i.e. the
time since 0001-01-01 measured in 100-nanosecond intervals.

The code from your provided link [Swift: convert NSDate to c# ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620342/swift-convert-nsdate-to-c-sharp-ticks) can be translated to Swift easily:

```
// Swift 2:
extension NSDate {
    var ticks: UInt64 {
        return UInt64((self.timeIntervalSince1970 + 62_135_596_800) * 10_000_000)
    }
}

// Swift 3:
extension Date {
    var ticks: UInt64 {
        return UInt64((self.timeIntervalSince1970 + 62_135_596_800) * 10_000_000)
    }
}
```

Example (Swift 3):

```
let ticks = Date().ticks
print(ticks) // 636110903202288256
```

or as a string:

```
let sticks = String(Date().ticks)
print(sticks)
```

And while are are at it, the reverse conversion from ticks to `Date`
would be

```
// Swift 2:
extension NSDate {
    convenience init(ticks: UInt64) {
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(ticks)/10_000_000 - 62_135_596_800)
    }
}

// Swift 3:
extension Date {
    init(ticks: UInt64) {
        self.init(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(ticks)/10_000_000 - 62_135_596_800)
    }
}
```

Example (Swift 3):

```
let date = Date(ticks: 636110903202288256)
```

Comment: This worked pretty good. I used this on NSDate instead of Date.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a solution that I find very elegant. I extended NSDate (although it's just Date now in Swift 3) to include a toMillis() func which will give you the Int64 value of the date object that you're working with.

```
extension Date {
    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let currentTimeStamp = Date().toMillis()
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however it returns only a 13-digit timestamp like this: 1475492283055. I need 18 digit.

Answer (score 12):

**In Swift:**

if you want to makeit as global variable see below code:

```
var Timestamp: String {
   return "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)"
}
```

Then, you can call it

```
println("Timestamp: \(Timestamp)")
```

The *1000 is for miliseconds, if you'd prefer, you can remove that. If keep it as an NSTimeInterval.

```
var Timestamp: NSTimeInterval {
    return NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
}
```

**In Objective C:**

If your want to declare as symbolic constant see below code:

```
#define TimeStamp [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000]
```

Then Call it like this:

```
NSString * timestamp = TimeStamp;
```

Or create a global method:

```
- (NSString *) timeStamp {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000];
}
```

**Have a Note:** The 1000 is to convert the timestamp to milliseconds. You can remove this if you prefer your timeInterval in seconds.