# Cannot use HashMap for TIMESTAMP in child

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I am trying a new timestamp, and want to insert it as a child. How to do that?

I have read this post:
[Write serverValue.timestamp as child in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885604/write-servervalue-timestamp-as-child-in-firebase) .. and still don't understand

I've tried to enter `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` into child and unsuccessful.

This my code:

```java
Object timestamp = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
reference.child(String.valueOf(timestamp)).child(uid).child("Status").setValue(cA);
```

I've read this:

[How to save the current date/time when I add new value to Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43584244/how-to-save-the-current-date-time-when-i-add-new-value-to-firebase-realtime-data)

I follow the code in it, and not work properly -->

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: timestamp cannot be inserted into the `child()`@Mustafa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` can only be written into a value, it cannot be used as the key in the database. So if you want to store the timestamp, you will have to write it as the value of a property. If you want to have chronologically ordered, unique keys, use the `push()` method.

So combined:

```
reference.push().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```